# Opening and Closing Pipes

Tags: c#, pipe, memory-efficient

If I am calling my server pipe 10 times a second should I close the pipe between calls or somehow keep them open?

This is my code so far:

```
    public static void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the pipe
            pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
            // End waiting for the connection
            pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);
            byte[] imageData = new byte[100000];
            pipeServer.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

            // Pass message back to calling form
            PipeMessage.Invoke(imageData);

            // Kill original sever and create new wait server
            //pipeServer.Close();
            //pipeServer = null;

            //PipeServer.PipeMessage -= new DelegateMessage(PipesMessageHandler);
            pipeServer.Disconnect();
            pipeServer.Close();
            pipeServer.Dispose();
            pipeServer = null;

            pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In,       1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            // Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `catch { return; }` Well, well. I hope this code always runs on a perfect machine in a perfect environment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Hi, you are quite right. I just put a stub there for now. I intend to finish this off later..

Comment: Depend on the pipe buffer size.  The data rate and transfer size is easily large enough to keeping it opened.